# Visual Studio 2017 - Team Explorer Builds 'Page not found'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, visual-studio-2017

We are using XAML builds in TFS 2015.

In the team explorer, builds tab in **Visual Studio 2017** (but still connecting to the TFS 2015 server) all of a sudden I am seeing the following 'Page not found' message and none of my XAML builds appear:

[image]

This happened after removing a TFS 2015 connection, then connecting to a TFS 2017 instance, then deleting the 2017 connection and then re-connecting to to the previous TFS 2015 instance.

I have tried

- Clearing the MEFComponentCache folder
- Running devenv /setup
- Completely uninstalling and re-installing VS2017

... and I'm still getting this error each time I connect to my TFS server. I also have VS2015 installed and this does show the builds but 2017 does not. A lot of the other posts on this issue seem to related to VS2015 but not 2017. I'm guessing something has changed here. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it please?

Comment: If you download fiddler and block the requests with the proxy and then try reconnecting, does this work? I say try with fiddler because it can show light into some of the http proxy misses. You should still be able to execute a cmd in your developer tools for VS. But in all honesty, knowing MS, they put a checkbox somewhere to "enable" the "disabled".

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with TFS, but it is possible, that Visual Studio 2017 has added some files, like setting-files on your system and if you delete VS17 the files will not be deleted.

I think you can try two options:

1. You can remove VS17 again and run a programm to clean up your PC, like [this clean up tool](http://www.avg.com/us-en/tuneup-utilities). After that you can install VS17 again and check, whether the problem is solved.
2. You can upgrade your TFS15 instance to TFS17. See [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started) or [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/walkthrough) link for more informations.

Attention, I'm new with that, it is only an idea and make BACKUPS!! ;)